# Exec returning more than expected

Tags: php, linux, exec

I have a php script that runs via a cron job.

I have an exec command in the script like so:

```
exec("ps -u bob -o user:20,%cpu,cmd | awk 'NR>1' | grep vlc | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2",$cpu,$return)
```

This gets me the cpu form a process run by a specific user, if the process exists. When run via the command line I get say 21 or nothing at all depending on if the process is running or not. However, when running vai the PHP script, I get the following:

```
[0] => bob 0.0 /bin/sh -c php /home/bob/restart.php bob
[1] => bob 0.0 php /home/bob/restartStream.php bob
[2] => bob 0.0 sh -c ps -u bob -o user:20,%cpu,cmd | awk NR
```

It seems to be returning all the recent commands executed as opposed to the result of the command executed.

I have seen some posts which show the use of `2>&1` which I believe redirects the stdin and stdout or soemthing similar. However I have tried this in my command like so:

```
ps -u bob -o user:20,%cpu,cmd | awk 'NR>1' | grep vlc | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 2>&1
```

But it does not seem to make a difference. Can any give me any pointers as to why this is occurring and what can possibly be done to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear out `$cpu` before you call `exec`. It appends the new output to the end of the array, it doesn't overwrite it.

You can also get rid of `grep`, `tr`, and `cut` and do all the processing of the output in `awk`

```
$cpu = array();
exec("ps -u bob -o user:20,%cpu,cmd | awk 'NR>1 && /vlc/ && !/awk/ {print $2}'",$cpu,$return);
```

The `!/awk/` keeps it from matching the `awk` line, since that contains `vlc`.

Comment: I just started messing with pipes and cutting etc and your solution is easy to modify and works amazingly. Really big thanks for the help, it is much appreciated. Looks like I have some reading on awk.